# windows batch file: concatenate string not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

In my batch file, I have 2 variables `FOLDER_WITH_PATH` and `FILE_NAME`. This is how I set their values:

```
set FOLDER_WITH_PATH="\\server1\project\CC1"
set FILE_NAME="Db20221021.bak"
echo %FOLDER_WITH_PATH%
echo %FILE_NAME%
```

Now I want to create a variable `FULL_FILE_NAME` by concatenating value of `FOLDER_WITH_PATH` then `\` and then value of `FILE_NAME`. So the value of `FULL_FILE_NAME` should be `\\server1\project\CC1\Db20221021.bak`.

But I have not been able to do it.

When I tried `set FULL_FILE_NAME=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%FILE_NAME%`, I get its value as `"\\server1\project\CC1"\"Db20221021.bak"` which is wrong.

When I tried `set FULL_FILE_NAME="%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%FILE_NAME%"`, I get its value as `""\\server1\project\CC1"\"Db20221021.bak""` which is wrong.

When I tried `set "FULL_FILE_NAME=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%FILE_NAME%"`, I get its value as `"\\server1\project\CC1"\"Db20221021.bak"` which is wrong.

Comment: You shoun't include the quotes in the variable values, because you'll always run into trouble when concatenating. The best syntax is `set "VAR=Value"`, so the quotes are not part of the value, but special characters are still protected (this only works with [command extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) enabled, but this is the default configuration anyway). If you have quotes in a value and you can't change its assignment for some reason, use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to remove them: `for %I in (%VAR%) do set "VAR=%~I"` (use `%%I`/`%%~I` in a batch file)…

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as below :

---

```bat
@echo off
set "FOLDER_WITH_PATH=\\server1\project\CC1"
set "FILE_NAME=Db20221021.bak"
Set "FULL_FILE_NAME=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%FILE_NAME%"
echo FOLDER_WITH_PATH = "%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%"
echo FILE_NAME = "%FILE_NAME%"
echo FULL_FILE_NAME = "%FULL_FILE_NAME%"
pause
```

Comment: The batch file is actually receiving the FOLDER_WITH_PATH and FILE_NAME as arguments: `set FOLDER_WITH_PATH=%1` and `set FILE_NAME=%2`